# How to use all the four nodes to make the connection to cassandra database

Tags: java, cassandra, astyanax

I have started working with Cassandra database recently and I am using Netflix client to populate and read the data from Cassandra database.

I have a single cluster with four nodes. I have created keyspace like this-

```
        create keyspace profilekeyspace
        with placement_strategy = 'NetworkTopologyStrategy'
        and strategy_options = {DC2 : 1, DC1 : 1}
        and durable_writes = true;
```

And my column family name is- `profile_columnfamily`

These are my four nodes-

```
      lp-host01.vip.slc.qa.host.com:9160
      lp-host02.vip.slc.qa.host.com:9160
      lp-host03.vip.phx.qa.host.com:9160
      lp-host04.vip.phx.qa.host.com:9160
```

Now currently I am using only one node from the above to make a connection to Cassandra database and populate the data. But my DBA's said, you need to use all the four nodes to make the connection.

```
private AstyanaxContext<Keyspace> context;

private CassandraAstyanaxConnection() {

    context = new AstyanaxContext.Builder()
    .forCluster("TEST CLUSTER")
    .forKeyspace("PROFILE")
    .withAstyanaxConfiguration(new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()     
        .setDiscoveryType(NodeDiscoveryType.RING_DESCRIBE)
    )
    .withConnectionPoolConfiguration(new ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl("MyConnectionPool")
        .setPort(9160)
        .setMaxConnsPerHost(1)
        .setSeeds("lp-host01.vip.slc.qa.host.com:9160:9160")//using only node from above to make the connection
    )
    .withAstyanaxConfiguration(new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()     
        .setCqlVersion("3.0.0")
        .setTargetCassandraVersion("1.2"))
    .withConnectionPoolMonitor(new CountingConnectionPoolMonitor())
    .buildKeyspace(ThriftFamilyFactory.getInstance());

    context.start();
    keyspace = context.getEntity();

    emp_cf = ColumnFamily.newColumnFamily(
        "PROFILE_COLUMNFAMILY",
        StringSerializer.get(),
        StringSerializer.get());
}
```

Now I am not sure how to use all the four nodes to make the connection using Netflix client? Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The seeds list is a comma separated list.  So you can just add the rest in the setSeeds call:

`setSeeds("server1:9160,server2:9160,server3:9160")`

Also, Astyanax will discover the other servers in the ring.  You only need to list one to discover all the others, but should that server be down you want to list more.  It is very much like the seeds list in cassandra.yaml.

Note you have duplicated the port in your line:

> .setSeeds("lp-host01.vip.slc.qa.host.com:9160:9160")

Comment: Yeah, I will correct that. By mistake it was. So in general you are saying we should use only one node to make the connection. But for some reason suppose that particular node is down? Then the whole connection to Cassandra database will be lost? So in that case, best way is to make the connection to all the four nodes and if any one of them is down, other nodes can be used to make the connection? Right?

Comment: The list given to setSeeds is not the list of nodes to connect to, it is the list of nodes used a seed to discover all the rest of the nodes. Then Astyanax connects to all of them. However, if you have a single seed node and it is down, then when your app starts up it won't find any nodes so will fail. For this reason you want a few nodes listed as a seed, but it doesn't need to be all of them.

Comment: Thanks Richard. That perfectly makes sense. One last question, can you check if there is any issue with the way I am making connection to Cassandra database which can hamper the performance while reading the data? As the above snippet code, will be in my Singleton class so I am creating the connection only once and then I am reusing it every time.

Comment: This creates a connection pool.  As long as you use it with multithreaded access you will get good performance.

Comment: Yes, I am using with Multithreaded code and just creating the connection once and then reusing it every time. So you think it should be fine right?

Comment: Yes, that's how it is designed.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I have one more question related to Netflix client, Can you take a look into that as well? This is the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180562/measure-the-read-latency-in-cassandra-database-using-netflix-client). Any help will be appreciated. Thanks